# Is the sentence "Don't you cry" correct?

Tags: syntax

Is the sentence "[Don't you cry](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zRIbf6JqkNc)" (or don't you speak, don't you cry etc.) is correct? For me, as ELL, it looks weird to see pronoun (in this case "**you**") in such sentence - as an order rather than a question. I expected it to be: "don't cry" instead of "don't you cry". what is the explanation for that?

Comment: Related: [Why do we say "don't you dare"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/341897/191178), [Don't you do this vs Don't do this](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/210323/191178) on ELU

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with that. It's just a normal structure of imperative with a visible subject. You can use it to convey a tone of friendly encouragement.

This structure can also be used to express impatience or irritation. It creates an agressive hectoring effect.

"Don't you call me your friend!"

Answer (score 0):

Don't cry.

Don't you cry.

The former sentence is a normal imperative negative sentence. The latter can also be treated so as an imperative.  They have the same meaning; you are asking the listener, you, not to cry.  You are using the pronoun you in the second sentence to emphasize the listener, you.